# Disable Caches In Umbraco Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I've tried to edit content from "cmsPropertyData" table...
After i've republished cache using "www.testdomain.com/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true" page.
It works fine on website, but admin panel still has an old content...
Can someone explain how to remove or disable caches in Umbraco admin panel, please?

Comment: maybe run this before republishing the cache? 'Truncate table cmsContentXml' on the db

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not helped. It's very strange as if i just amend /Config/umbracoSettings.config file and save it, content in admin will be also refreshed

Comment: Would you have a persistent cache in app_data? Maybe this isn't being refreshed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works fine. Do you know another way to do that? I'd like to just edit "dataNtext" column in "cmsPropertyData" table and Umbraco system will not cache anything on website and admin panel.

Comment: No unfortunately. You probably shouldn't update the tables directly - the approved way is to use the service api https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Models/ContentType unfortunately I find the same problem with them I have to rebuild the cache afterwards. It's on my list of things to investigate when I have a moment :-)

Comment: You can turn off caching - we turn off the app_data cache. I wouldn't turn off the XML cache though - performance would go through the floor

Comment: DO NOT delete the contents of cmsContentXml, especially on a large site with many, many nodes. Calling the republish dialog just repopulates the cache from that table, so if you clear it, your content cache will be empty! You'd have to do a save and publish with children from the context menu of your home node to get the table contents back, and on a large site, that can take several hours.